# Java argo JSON how to?

Tags: java, xml, json, jsp

My database structure is going large.

First, I am confused between JSON and XML. Then, I have chosen JSON to store data in the database.

I am trying to compile an example given on official website.
But I am unable to do so.

Here's my code:

```
import static argo.jdom.JsonNodeFactories.*;

public class argojson
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JsonRootNode json = object( field("name", string("Black Lace")), field("sales", 

        number("110921")), field("totalRoyalties", number("10223.82")), field("singles", 

        array( string("Superman"), string("Agadoo") )) );

    }
}
```

**Error**

```
JsonRootNode error: cannot find symbol
```

**Official website**

```
http://argo.sourceforge.net/documentation.html
```

Comment: Neither JSON nor XML should be necessary to store data in a (relational) database...

Comment: i know, but i want because it is going big

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually included the jars on the classpath at compile time?

Looking at http://argo.sourceforge.net/javadoc/argo/jdom/JsonRootNode.html it looks like you need to

```
import argo.jdom.JsonRootNode
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguements you have passed in your code

```
object( field("name", string("Black Lace")), field("sales", 

number("110921")), field("totalRoyalties", number("10223.82")), field("singles", 

array( string("Superman"), string("Agadoo") )) )
```

is not json data actually. First learn about json data format. Then try giving correct arguement.

You could use jakson or Gson to convert data to and from java objects.